# Unable to Show Admob ads in Unity | Development Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, admob

I would like to ask for advice. I am able to see the admob ads in my emulator and also with real device, if in my Build Settings the Development Build is Checked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwjvD.jpg)

But if not, no Ads at all.
Will it be okay to build an APK to be released in Google Play Store even if the Development Build is checked?
Sorry I'm new in Unity.

The Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;
 using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdScript : MonoBehaviour
 {

```
 bool isShown;
 InterstitialAd interstitial;

 void Start()
 {

     RequestInterstitialAds();
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if (GameControl.isGameOver)
     {
         if (!isShown)
         {
             isShown = true;
             showInterstitialAd();
         }
     }
 }

 public void showInterstitialAd()
 {

     if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
     {
         interstitial.Show();

     }

 }


 private void RequestInterstitialAds()
 {
     //Testing
     string adID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";

     //Live
     //string adID = "MY ADD ID";                     

     #if UNITY_ANDROID
     string adUnitId = adID;
     #elif UNITY_IOS
     string adUnitId = adID;
     #else
     string adUnitId = adID;
     #endif

     // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
     interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

     //Test
     AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
     .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)       // Simulator.
     .AddTestDevice("89D1DA1F820CE28BA86223A1C34****")  // My test device.
     .Build();

     //Production
     //AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

     //Register Ad Close Event
     interstitial.OnAdClosed += Interstitial_OnAdClosed;

     //Load the interstitial with the request.
     interstitial.LoadAd(request);

     //Debug.Log("AD LOADED XXX");

 }


 private void Interstitial_OnAdClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
 //Resume Play Sound
 }
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot this at the top

```
MobileAds.initialize(appID);
```